# Emacs: print key binding for a command or list all key bindings

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

In Emacs (GNU 23.2, *nix), how can I:

1. list the key sequences bound to a particular command? For example, how can we list all the key sequences that execute `save-buffers-kill-emacs`, with the output of key sequences bound to it? Assuming we can do this, listing the key sequences bound to `goto-line` should print the output: `M-g g` on a default install.
2. list all key-bindings? Does `C-h b` do this? Would it print my own bindings?

I am aware that executing the command directly can print a key sequence it can be activated with, but it doesn't always do so, and a few things happen, including:
(1) the output doesn't remain for long, (2) the command is executed.

I want a *command* that lists for me (preferably all) the bindings attached to a given command, without executing the command, or something like that.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

1. <kbd>C-h f</kbd> (or <kbd>M-x describe-function</kbd>) will show you the bindings for a command.
2. You are correct, <kbd>C-h b</kbd> (or <kbd>M-x describe-bindings</kbd>) will show you all bindings. <kbd>C-h m</kbd> (<kbd>M-x describe-mode</kbd>) is also handy to list bindings by mode.

You might also try <kbd>C-h k</kbd> (<kbd>M-x describe-key</kbd>) to show what command is bound to a key. For instance, on my machine `save-buffers-kill-emacs` isn't bound to anything, but <kbd>C-h k C-x C-c</kbd> tells me that <kbd>C-x C-c</kbd> is bound to `save-buffers-kill-terminal`. It will list all bindings for the command at the same time.

Comment: +1, Also there is `C-h c` (or `M-x describe-key-briefly`) which just gives the function that a key is assigned to in the mini-buffer space.

Comment: Not sure if this should be a separate question, but is it possible to show all keybindings/functions which start with a particular key? For example, what bindings *start* with <f2>? Pressing <f2> after "C-h m" does not work as Emacs is waiting for a second key.

Comment: Asked as a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330510/show-emacs-keybindings-which-start-with-a-particular-key

Answer (score 42):

How about just

```
M-x where-is <COMMAND>
```

You get the same information as you'd get with <kbd>C-h f</kbd>.

Also bound to <kbd>C-h w</kbd>, <kbd><f1> w</kbd> and <kbd><help> w</kbd>.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer to the first question, since `describe-function` doesn't list all bindings for functions like `ignore` or `self-insert-command`.