# How do I list the defined keys in emacs isearch-mode?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

How do I list the defined keys in emacs isearch-mode?

Based on [Emacs: print key binding for a command or list all key bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845934/emacs-print-key-binding-for-a-command-or-list-all-key-bindings) I have tried C-h m, but I cannot do that while in isearch-mode (<kbd>C-h</kbd> and <kbd>M-x</kbd> seem to cancel out of it)

Thanks,
-Shawn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to get the help page:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `isearch-mode-help`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find everything in the documention of isearch-forward. Do `C-h f isearch-forward`

Comment: Ah great, thanks! I didn't realize that help page would show me all the current keybindings.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a listing of the bindings by typing <kbd>C-h b</kbd> during search (Emacs 23.2).  Also available are <kbd>C-h m</kbd> (which worked for me) and <kbd>C-h k</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to try this:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/isearch%2b.el

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus

And <kbd>C-h M-k</kbd> (`describe-keymap`) in this library will let you know the bindings in any keymap (e.g. `isearch-mode-map`):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/help-fns%2b.el

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>C-s C-h b</kbd>

Which I found out using <kbd>C-s C-h ?</kbd>

Comment: I cannot parse the output of that:

Key translations:
key             binding
---             -------

C-x  Prefix Command

C-x 8  iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map

^L
`cua--ena-cua-keys-keymap' Minor Mode Bindings:
key             binding
---             -------

C-c  Prefix Command
C-v  yank
C-x  Prefix Command
C-z  undo
ESC  Prefix Command
<remap>  Prefix Command

Comment: Hm, that didn't come out so well, but it has ^L randomly in the text and seems to list all keybindings in an odd order...